java: Incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.time.Duration
Unfortunalety I am getting error message "java: Incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.time.Duration" thrown in my login_page class.
Can anyone help me fixing this problem?
enter image description here
enter image description here
I am trying to execute my pretty simple test automation using page object model and would expect it to work without errors.
Thank you very much in advance!

check and consider this link: Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. || the error message means: code is providing  an int, but a Duration is expected (e.g. in a method call or an assignment) To create a Duration use some of its method like in Duration.ofSeconds(10) - see the javadoc

Pass Duration not int
The second arg in the WebDriverWait is of type Duration not int. This should fix it
Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds(10);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(utils.driver, duration);


Also, the statics in your utils class have a code smell. You should use Dependency Injection instead of the static methods / members

try to create object by using the following statement
WebDriverWait expWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(3));
WebDriverWait is use to provide explicit wait, and to do so we have to create object of WebDriverWait class, and constructor is parameterize which accept 2 arguments which are as follow

WebDriver
Duration

